# Unwanted italics in page headers (classicthesis)

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, sectioning, header-footer, classicthesis

In my section titles I sometimes have to use italic letters for the entry in the table of contents. Unfortunately, this results in italic letters in the page headers. How can I avoid this? The page headers should look like the section titles.

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,
        footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,
        BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[parts,beramono,eulerchapternumbers,%
    listings,manychapters,%
    floatperchapter]{classicthesis} 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-18]
\section[\textit{Second} section]{Second section}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you define a short title for your section or chapter, the `classicthesis` format takes this as your header text as well. With the command `\sectionmark{}` (and similarly `\chaptermark{}`) you are able to define a custom header version of your title. In this case, you are forced to use it in order to restore the original title writing.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,
        footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,
        BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[parts,beramono,eulerchapternumbers,%
    listings,manychapters,%
    floatperchapter]{classicthesis} 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-18]
\section[\textit{Second} section]{Second section}
\sectionmark{Second section}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't know, that there's such an easy way. I thought I have to change something in the thesis style or add something to the preamble.

Comment: @djanna Glad I could help. If the answer works for you, you should accept it as such. Accepting the answer and upvoting it is the way to say thank you here (and it reduces the number of "unanswered questions").